# Simple javascript slider issue w/ html

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out why this simple code isn't working.  I'm implementing this:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fadeslideshow.js">

/***********************************************
* Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library     (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [750, 500], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect     dimensions of largest image
        imagearray: [
        ["/images/allimages/vdance750x500.png", "", "", "Caption"],
        ["/images/allimages/vpoca750x500.png",  "", "", ""],
        ["/images/allimages/vhat750x500.png", "", "", "" ],
        ["/images/allimages/vdance750x500.png", "", "", ""] //<--no trailing comma     after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})
</script>


<title>Vanadia's Site</title>





</head>

<body>

<div id="fadeshow1"></div>

<br />


</body>
</html>
```

I am new to coding and wondering if there is a syntax error... all the images are in the right spot.  I dont understand why this isn't working!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there's a syntax error, your debugger should tell you. hit Ctrl-Shift-I in chrome, opera or firefox. Hit f12 in ie.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your doc type and opening html and head tags? Maybe you just didn't include them here, but make sure they aren't missing from your document. Aside from that, check your browser's JavaScript console to see if you're throwing an error. If you are, please post it for all to see.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and changed the image paths (demo: jsfiddle.net/hJKMy/). 
It is likely that your image paths are incorrect.